# Template variable throwing undefined error while running jasmine test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm getting the below error while running unit test case,

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`.

Below is my Spec,

```
describe('ListComponent', () => {
  let component: ListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListComponent>;

  const mock = {
    "type": "list",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "unordered-list-item",
          "text": "Unordered Item One",
          "depth": 1,
        }
      ]
  }
  cacheTestbed({
    imports: [ContentComponentsModule],

  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.contentOnCreate(mock)
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This my HTML,

```
<ng-container *ngIf="listItems.type==='unordered-list-item'">
  <ul *ngIf="listItems.children.length > 0" class="bw-information-ul-with-disc">
    <bw-information-recursive-list *ngFor="let child of listItems.children" [child]="child"></bw-information-recursive-list>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

`listItems.type` is undefined. If I comment the html code all test case are getting passed.

I even tried to assign mock values to `listItems` inside `beforeEach` but it dosen't work getting the same error.

Please help.

*********** UPDATE *******

My Component spec

**Component.Ts**

```
export class ListComponent {
  public listItems: RecursiveList;

  contentOnCreate(values: ListItems): void {
    this.listItems = this.createListTree(values.items);
  }

  createListTree(listItem: ListItem[]): Item {
    const root: Item = { text: 'root', children: [], type: listItem[0].type }
    const stack: Item[] = []
    const firstChildOfRoot = {
      text: listItem[0].text,
      children: [],
      type: listItem[0].type
    }
    root.children.push(firstChildOfRoot)
    stack.push(root)
    stack.push(firstChildOfRoot)

    for (let i = 1; i < listItem.length; i++) {
      const flatItem = listItem[i]
      const depthDiff = flatItem.depth - (stack.length - 1)
      if (depthDiff <= 0) {
        this.removeFromEnd(stack, -depthDiff + 1)
      }
      const stackTop = stack[stack.length - 1]
      const newEl = {
        text: flatItem.text,
        children: [],
        type: flatItem.type
      }
      stackTop.children.push(newEl)
      stack.push(newEl)
    }
    return root
  }

  removeFromEnd<T>(array: T[], count: number) {
    array.splice(array.length - count, count)
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of the component, and post the code that you tried.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: The contentOnCreate() method should be called *before* the call to detectChanges(). But this shows a design problem in the component anyway: when will this contentOnCreate() method be called when the component is actually used in the app? Your template only works if listItems has been initialized before the template is rendered for the first time, and it doesn't seem to be, so you need to test if listItems is defined before trying to access its type.

Comment: @stacks as I provided the answer by putting my time into it. it would really makes sense if you provide your input to appreciate my effort

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `fixture.detectChanges();` after `component.contentOnCreate`:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.contentOnCreate(mock)
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```